# Marketing games for the android - what are the best sites to contact for reviews/advertising?

Tags: android

WE are in final dev stages of our latest game and want to release it for the android market. 
What are the best sites to contact for reviews/advertising that specifically target the android users???

Answer (score 1):

Triplepoint PR helped Dave Whatley sell a few hundred thousand iOS copies of geoDefense. Chris Pruett, creator of Replica Island and Google employee talked about the importance of PR somewhere on his [blog](http://replicaisland.blogspot.com/) and also in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic). He has all kinds of great graphs and stuff too.

Also, TalkAndroid and AndroidCentral seem to always be happy to do reviews of apps. I personally follow them both on Twitter.

Comment: Thanks very much for this info! I"m a Producer at Blowfish Studios in Sydney Australia. "Qbism HD" was our first game release and we are now working on our next title which will be released for Android and iOs! Thanks again for your help!